# How list comprehension behaves in a for loop

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Why do the two scenarios below behave differently?

First:

```
x = []
[x.append('f8') for num in range(8)]
print(x)
```

Result:

```
['f8', 'f8', 'f8', 'f8', 'f8', 'f8', 'f8', 'f8']
```

Second:

```
x = []
print(list(x.append('f8') for num in range(8)))
```

Result:

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Why is `None` passed in the second case? How does list comprehension behave here?

Comment: the return value of the `.append` method is `None`. it doesn't return anything, it just modifies the list in place.

Comment: by the way: the list comprehension is not the correct tool for "do this task some number of times". for that, you should use a regular for loop: `for num in range(8): x.append('f8')`. the list comprehension is for "fill a new list with these values". `.append` is a task, or action, you are doing *to* the list. it does not return anything.

Comment: Well, in this particular case the list comprehension *is* the correct tool for "make a list consisting of these items", and if you use one you shouldn't mix it with `append`: `x = ['f8' for _ in range(8)]`

Comment: @mkrieger1 yeah, you're right, didn't think of that.

Comment: i was learning something over internet and was using zip function where i tried putting this directly but got none in combination of other values. So i shortened the problem and got to this code. Thanks very much for clearing the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the list `.append()` operation is `None`. Therefore the list

```
[x.append('f8') for num in range(8)]
```

is in fact equal to

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

but in the process of creating this list of `None`s, there is the side effect that `x` is appended to. So the two results are not in conflict at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are printing the list `x`, which had `'f8'` appended 8 times.

In the second case, you are printing a list (not `x`) which contains the return value of `x.append(...)` 8 times. Since `append()` returns `None` this is the output you get.